# List cannot be resolved in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, import

Below code is for display an images from server folder but List is showing cannot be resolved type. Uploaded the images into the folder using the servlet code "private static final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "upload";" now i want display all the images to jsp page. please help

```html
<%@ page import ="java.io.*"%>;
<%@ page import ="java.io.File.*"%>;
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import ="java.util.ArrayList.*"%>
<%@ page import ="java.util.List.*"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>File Upload Example</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div id="result">
            <h3>${requestScope["message"]}</h3>
        </div>

        <%
            List imageUrlList = new ArrayList(); //List cannot be resolved type
            File imageDir = new File("Upload");
            for (File imageFile : imageDir.listFiles()) {
                String imageFileName = imageFile.getName();

                // add this images name to the list we are building up  
                imageUrlList.add(imageFileName);

            }
            request.setAttribute("imageUrlList", imageUrlList);
        %>
    <c:forEach var="img" items="${imageUrlList}">  
        <img src="${imageUrlList}"/>  
    </c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your import are wrong, List/ArrayList are classes and not packages so you need to remove .*

```
<%@ page import ="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import ="java.util.List"%>
```

Comment: Images are not displaying from above code. I am getting this error HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page  showing with for loop line. pls help

Comment: Please open a different question

Answer (score 0):

remove asterik(*)
<%@ page import ="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import ="java.util.List"%>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).